# How to pass model from one action to another action in Sitecore MVC

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have one scenario for which i am looking for solution.

I have two .cshtml pages  **abc.cshtml and xyz.cshtml** which is associated with **Item A and Item B**.

Now, Page abc has textbox and button which is passing text value to Action using FormMethod.Post like below. It will appear when i request for ***domain/A***

**View**

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post)

{

@Html.TextBoxfor()

}
```

**Controller**

```cs
public ActionResult About(LoginModel model)

{
   List<Car> result = new List<Car>();

   result = service.GetResult(model.textboxvalue); //Here i am passing textbox value to method which returns list.

   return View();

   // Now i want to display values in result List on xyz.cshtml i.e. on http://domain/B   
   // So how can i pass whole model (which consist of other property as well including list) to another Sitecore Item i.e. Item B
}
```

**Summary:**

1. User will hit the URL **domain/A** , fill the textbox and Click the button.
2. Back end will fill the model. After that, I want to redirect to **domain/B** with filled model to show that values.

I have referred following link:

https://mhwelander.net/2014/05/22/passing-data-between-actions-in-sitecore-mvc/

which says **Just like in regular ASP.NET MVC, you cannot pass complex types – like complete models – between actions.** and it seems true as Sitecore MVC execution pipeline is different from ASP.NET MVC. Also, i have tried but no luck yet.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you don't want to pass your model to another action, you want to return it back to be displayed on the view?

Can you not just return to the view you want with your model?

```
return View("xyz", model);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also add hidden fields inside the form and your properties will be filled at the moment the user POST the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post)
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
     @Html.TextBoxfor()
}
```